# i am getting from server in recycler view but I am getting No layout manager attached; skipping layout error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

```
// Service call for getting data from server
            ServiceFactory.getProfessionalResourceService().getProductList(
                    SearchagainActivity.this, fileType, searchText,token,Appversion,
                    new IRequestListener<ProductProfessionalResponse>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onRequestFailure(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            CommonUtilities.showErrorDialog(SearchagainActivity.this, null);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRequestSuccess(ProductProfessionalResponse response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        if(response !=null&& response.getmServerResponse().getmStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
                        {

    mProductSearch=new ArrayList();
                            mProduct=new ArrayList<Product>();
                            mProfessional=new ArrayList<ProfessionalResource>();

       ProductProfessional details = response.getmFavourites();
                            mProduct=details.getmProductList();


    mProfessional=details.getmFilesList();
                              if (mProfessional != null && !mProfessional.isEmpty())
          //get professional resource from server                             {
        mAdapter=new ProfResCustomGalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProfessional);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                       }else
                                       {
 //getting product from server 
                    mAdapterProduct=new ProductListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mProduct);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterProduct);
                                       }

                                 /*   */

                                  /*if (bFavouriteMode)
                                      resetFileAdapter(true);
                                  else
                                      refreshAdapter(true);*/


                            //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterProduct);

                        }
                        }



                        @Override
                        public void onResponseError(String errorCode) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //CommonUtilities.showErrorDialog(SearchagainActivity.this, null);
                            mTvErrorMsg.setText("Product is not available");
                            dialog.show();
                        }








                    } );

        }


     /*   *//**
         * to get the search string entered in the searchBox of the 
        /**
         * Set RecyclerView's LayoutManager to the one given.
         * 
         * @param layoutManagerType Type of layout manager to switch to.
         */
```

/*attached the layout to recycler view, this is method from where i am attching the layout to recyclerview*/
            public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager() {
                ;// Log.d(TAG, "setRecyclerViewLayoutManager()");
                int scrollPosition = 0;

```
            // If a layout manager has already been set, get current scroll
            // position.
            if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
                scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                        .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            }
            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, SPAN_COUNT);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);

        }
```

Comment: where are u callling the method

Comment: i am calling after getServicecall method in onCreate method

Comment: see my answer for more info

Comment: in onCreate method, after component initialization i called getService method and setRecyclerViewLayoutManager() but i am not able to fetch the layout in recycleview

Comment: please post your complete activity code

Comment: can you tell me your emailid

Answer (score 0):

it is error logged by recyclerview when no layout manager is attached , till the time layout manager basically whenever it will try to layout view it will check if layoutmanager is attached and if not it will logged the error